# Axon: Deadline vs EventScheduler

Tags: axon

Hello I'm struggling to come up with the distinction between the `DeadlineManager` implementation of scheduling future events and `EventScheduler` and what is the best use case for either.

Say I need to schedule a task to be performed in 24 hours based on a command that happened today. Between now and then another event or command could occur that makes the scheduled event obsolete so now I need to cancel the scheduled event.

Can I use either interchangeably? If not - in this scenario what is the best choice or is there not enough information? What would inform my decision to use one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between scheduling an event or a deadline is what you want to happen when your scheduled time has passed.

When you schedule an event , that event will always be added to the eventstore after the scheduled time has passed.

When you schedule a deadline, no event will be added directly, but instead a `DeadlineHandler` annotated function will be called, in which you can then decide based on the current state of the aggregate or saga, what you want to do (if anything). So unless you apply an event yourself in the deadline handler, there will be no interaction with the eventstore.

Note that both can also be cancelled before the scheduled time has ended, using the `ScheduleToken` returned when scheduling an event, or using the `deadineId` and its name in the case of a deadline.

Some further information can be found in the reference guide:

https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/deadlines

https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/complex-business-transactions/deadline-handling

Comment: Thanks that helps clarify what was in the reference materials!